# Filtrar por columna tabla html con jquery, a través de inputs en el encabezado de la tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-tabla

Necesito que alguien me pueda orientar con este problema.
Tengo una tabla del cual programa turnos de personal, y necesito poder filtrar las columnas con datos extraídos desde `MySQL`, a modo de ejemplo sólo usaré datos representados en la tabla.

```js
 

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#search").keyup(function(){

        _this = this;

        

            $.each($("#datos tbody tr"), function() {

            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)

            $(this).hide();

            else

            $(this).show();

            });

        });

    });
```

```css
#datos thead
{
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<input type="text" placeholder="Ingresa algún parámetro..." class="form-control-sm form-control" id="search" style="border-radius:0px;width:280px;">

<br>
<table id="datos" class="table-bordered table-sm">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Apellido</th>
         <th>01-NOV</th>
         <th>02-NOV</th>
         <th>03-NOV</th>
         <th>04-NOV</th>
         <th>05-NOV</th> 
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Riquelme</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Roberto</td>
          <td>Andrade</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Tomas</td>
          <td>Riquelme</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>

</table>
```

El tema de todoes que el filtro de búsqueda funciona bien, pero quisiera intentar filtrarlo por columnas, es decir, que existan inputs debajo del encabezado de la columna y pueda filtrar de acuerdo a lo que se escribe en aquella columna. Un ejemplo sería algo como esto.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.search
{
  height:15px;
}
</style>


<br>
<table id="datos" class="table-bordered table-sm">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Nombre</th>
         <th>Apellido</th>
         <th>01-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" id="search" ></th>
         <th>02-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" id="search" ></th>
         <th>03-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" id="search" ></th>
         <th>04-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" id="search" ></th>
         <th>05-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" id="search" ></th> 
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Riquelme</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Roberto</td>
          <td>Andrade</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Tomas</td>
          <td>Riquelme</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>D</td>
          <td>T</td>
          <td>T</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>

</table>
```

¿Necesita alguna modificación el `jquery` que agregué arriba?, ¿Y que trabaje por clase y que sólo filtre los valores por columnas?.

**Favor evitar sugerir el uso de `datatables` porque la tabla con la que trabajo es demasiado grande(variedad de columnas) y sólo estoy necesitando esto para realizar filtros, tampoco el uso de `tablefilterfree`.**

Comment: La tabla muestra todo o está paginada en distintas páginas?

Comment: @matahombres, la tabla muestra todo, está en una pagina completa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Nunca pongas 2 atributos `id` con el mismo nombre

**Explicación:**
Como lo solucionaría yo sería añadir una clase a cada elemento del `tr`. Ej:

```
<tr>
    <td class="buscador_nombre"></td>
    <td class="buscador_apellidos"></td>
    <td class="buscador_date1"></td>
    <td class="buscador_date2"></td>
    <td class="buscador_date3"></td>
</tr>
```

Ya que estás utilizando JQuery y es mucho más flexible (y más fácil de utilizar) lo que haría seria añadir un atributo donde contenga el nombre y así me libro de código

```
<tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>01-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" busqueda="buscador_nombre"></th>
    <th>02-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" busqueda="buscador_apellidos"></th>
    <th>03-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" busqueda="buscador_date1"></th>
    <th>04-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" busqueda="buscador_date2"></th>
    <th>05-NOV <input type="text" class="search form-control-sm form-control" busqueda="buscador_date3"></th> 
</tr>
```

**Código:**
Básicamente JQuery hace selecciones como CSS (Que javascript sería `document.querySelector`), así que podemos utilizar más cómodamente clases

Los eventos que utilizaremos serán `keyup` y `keydown`. Utilizaremos `keydown` porque si mantienes se sigue poniendo la letra y `keyup` lo utilizaremos por si acaso llega a haber algún error con las teclas de borrado.
Para no tener que repetir código y que se quede más limpio posible haré una función y la llamaré con los dos eventos

```
$(".search").keyup(function(){
    rastreator($(this));
});
$(".search").keydown(function(){
    rastreator($(this));
});
function rastreator(elem){
    var rastrear="#datos tbody tr ."+elem.attr("busqueda");
    var contenido=elem.val();
    $(rastrear).each(function(){
        var texto=$(this).text();
        if(texto.startsWith(contenido)){
            $(this).parents("tr").show();
        }else{
            $(this).parents("tr").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Luego utilizo el atributo de `busqueda` y le añado la "dirección" hacia donde voy ha buscar. Luego compruebo con `startsWith()` si comienza por ese contenido (Si lo que quieres hacer es que contenga en vez de que empiece, utiliza `includes()`). Si es así, lo muestro el `tr`. Si es lo contrario, oculto el `tr`

**Ventajas de hacerlo así:**
Si en un futuro añades más columnas a la tabla o es una tabla diferente o cosas así, simplemente tienes que añadir un atributo `busqueda` y añadirle una clase al `td`

> Para hacerlo que pueda añadir más tablas solo tienes que cambiar estás dos líneas de código:
>  `var rastrear="tbody tr ."+elem.attr("busqueda");` y `$(this).parents("table").find(rastrear).each(....`

Comment: gracias.. trabaja muy bien.